# Are the "standard errors" that the glmRob command give you considered robust?

Tags: standards, glm, robust

I am running a glm to get PR for my binary outcome. I want to use the glmRob command to get robust standard errors. The output only says "std errors". Is the robust part implied given that in the description of the command on cran-project, it is called a robust generalized linear model? The description in cran does not specify either way whether output is assumed to be robust standard errors.